# How to tag products in Spree as "Recommended" and list them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want Spree index page to show "Recommended" Products. For this, I need to be able to mark products as "Recommended", and after list them.

I don't know the best way to do this, maybe with options? Or do I need to create a new field into `spree_products` ? How about listing them?

Thanks!

Comment: may this extension help you out https://github.com/paulcc/spree-recommendations

Comment: How do I install this? Copying each file? No gem included. @Kushal

Answer (score 1):

You can create a taxonomy named 'Recommended'. Then add the taxon named 'Recommend' to the products. Then in your controller you can retrieve the recommended products like this:

```
  @searcher = build_searcher(taxon: Spree::Taxon.find_by(name: 'Featured'), include_images: true)
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
```

Comment: Thanks @lunr , the thing is, I want the recommended products to show in the Spree Core page, which I have assigned in /shop . Which controller / action should I play with? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the home page? That should be the `home_controller.rb` in `spree/frontend/app/controllers/spree`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple work, you have to create new Boolean column in spree_products and show this column in back-end. Whenever you create new product just mark that check-box and save that product.

On front-end you simple show that products by `@product.recommended` and define scope in product.rb like`scope :recommended, -> { where(is_recommended: true) }`